# certificate authority "like" or similar service that provides open source audit and certificate proving project does not contain malicious code

Tags: certificates, audit

Compliance is not my area, so I apologize for the naive language, as I am having trouble explicitly articulating my want, beyond the following anecdote:

If one were to build a solution for an audience that only operates on a [zero trust](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_trust_networks) paradigm, and that audience's technical knowledge ranged from laymen users to ops engineers, it would behoove everyone involved (the author, the implementer and the user) to have some form of certificate, matched to a SHA, that could be validated against a set of authorities, whom would endorse that the SHA in question is most likely free of malicious code.

Sorry for the run-on sentence, as I said, I am having trouble articulating the need and I realize the above is juxtaposed to the idea of zero-trust, but when you boil it down, everything is dependent on some central component.

To put more simply, is there a means of providing a "seal of approval", matched against a given sha or set of hashes, that unsophisticated to sophisticated users could take with more than a grain of salt, and that can be programmatically validated against some agreed upon authority?

Comment: You might be aware of this already, but if you aren’t, it could be interesting to look into remote attestation. Then there’s identity management and access control. To deal with the “maliciousness” side of things, you’re looking at security audits (but they often miss security problems), and guaranteeing that binaries match audited source code (*e.g.* reproducible builds, but that’s not the full story). It’s all rather broad, and still very much work in progress in many areas... And having a set of central authorities, well that’s a whole other kettle of fish!

Comment: Maybe a better place for this kind of question: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions